# HTTPRequest() Error: This address cannot be used to locate server

Tags: android, windev

I'm trying to send information to a non WinDev server from a WM Android app by HTTPRequest() function when I get an error "This address cannot be used to locate server".

I made the call in this way.

```
lOk = HTTPRequest (cUrl, "", "", CDATA)
```

For testing I have 3 packages of different data, two weighing less than 2MB and one that weighs 23MB, the error only occurs in the 3rd case. In the 3 cUrl it's identical.

May HTTPRequest() function has a weight limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer myself.

CDATA was declared as String, it works for small packages but for a bigger weight only works if this variable is declared as a Buffer.